# Web address routing works fine with http.ListenAndServe, but fails with cgi.Serve()

Tags: go, routes

I'm working on a website using Go. The server constraints require that I use CGI. When I test the following code locally using http.ListenAndServe() (commented out below), the various handlers are called correctly depending on the address requested. However, if I use cgi.Serve() instead, the default router is executed for all addresses (i.e., the handler for "/" is always executed). I'd appreciate any clues as to how to fix the issue.

EDIT: Here is the simplest test case I can think of to show the problem:

//=============SIMPLIFIED CODE================//

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cgi"
)

func defaultHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Default")
}

func otherHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Other")
}

 func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/other", otherHandler)

    http.HandleFunc("/", defaultHandler)

    /*
        //Works fine
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    */

   //Always fires defaultHandler no matter the address requested
    err := cgi.Serve(nil)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

//=============CODE FROM ORIGINAL POST===================//

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cgi"
    "net/url"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-cas/cas"
)

func logoutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cas.RedirectToLogout(w, r)
}

func calendarHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if !cas.IsAuthenticated(r) {
        cas.RedirectToLogin(w, r)
}

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Calendar for %s", cas.Username(r))
}

func defaultHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if !cas.IsAuthenticated(r) {
        cas.RedirectToLogin(w, r)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there %s!", cas.Username(r))
}

func main() {
    u, _ := url.Parse("https://www.examplecasserver.com")

    client := cas.NewClient(&cas.Options{
        URL: u,
    })

    http.Handle("/logout", client.HandleFunc(logoutHandler))

    http.Handle("/calendar", client.HandleFunc(calendarHandler))

    http.Handle("/", client.HandleFunc(defaultHandler))

    /*
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
        }
    */

    err := cgi.Serve(nil)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the use of the cas client middleware? Perhaps try it with the simplest possible handlers first, without client.HandleFunc or any cas.xxx calls. You might find cas is redirecting to /.

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the post to add the simplest test case I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CGI program expects some variables to be set in order to build the request.

Probably there is some issue with the configuration of your web server in which the variables are either not set correctly or not named correctly.

To verify this:

1) Add this before calling `cgi.Serve` and you'll see how the right handler is called (`otherHandler`)

```
os.Setenv("REQUEST_METHOD", "get")
os.Setenv("SERVER_PROTOCOL", "HTTP/1.1")
os.Setenv("SCRIPT_NAME", "/other")
```

2) Add this at the beginning of the `main` to check how the variables are being set by the web server:

```
fmt.Println(os.Environ())
```

In that output, look for the CGI meta variables defined in the spec:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875

Look for the section "Request Meta-Variables" in that page, you are probably looking for the `SCRIPT_NAME` or `PATH_INFO` variables.

**EDIT**

From the variable values you pasted below, it seems the issue is that the REQUEST_URI contains an additional path component:

```
REQUEST_URI=/main.cgi/other
```

So the easiest fix would be for you to map the routes accordingly:

```
http.HandleFunc("/main.cgi/other", otherHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/", defaultHandler)  // or maybe /main.cgi
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing here, but here's a printout from one attempt:

REQUEST_SCHEME=http
CONTEXT_PREFIX=
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/home/user1/public_html
SERVER_ADMIN=webmaster@user1.mycpanel.sample.com
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/home/user1/public_html/main.cgi
REMOTE_PORT=45516
GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD=get
QUERY_STRING=
REQUEST_URI=/main.cgi/other
SCRIPT_NAME=/other
PATH_INFO=/other
PATH_TRANSLATED=/home/user1/public_html/other

Comment: Take a look here to see how Go builds the request based on those vars: https://golang.org/src/net/http/cgi/child.go?#L94

Comment: @Brent: see my edit in the answer based on what you pasted